# State of the art for automatic rhythm analysis

Tags: signal-analysis, algorithms, music

What are the currently most used and less error prone algorithms in the field of music information retrieval for beat detection and tracking?

Comment: feet, it is the most common algorithm run by meat computers

Comment: Equipped with soft drives